# How do I center a python console app window?

Tags: python, shell, console, window, os.system

I would like to know if there is a library/shell command that centers your python window.

For example,
`os.system('title TITLE HERE && mode con:cols=100 lines=40')`
creates a console window with a specified height and title. The os.system simply runs a shell command.

Is there a shell command to center the window?

Answer (score 0):

Yea you can. First install wmctrl with:

`sudo apt-get install wmctrl`

And than enter this code.

```
winname='foo'
IFS='x' read sw sh < <(xdpyinfo | grep dimensions | grep -o '[0-9x]*' | head -n1)
read wx wy ww wh < <(wmctrl -lG | grep $winname | sed 's/^[^ ]* *[^ ]* //;s/[^0-9 ].*//;')
wmctrl -r $winname -e 0,$(($sw/2-$ww/2)),$(($sh/2-$wh/2)),$ww,$wh
```

Replace `foo` with the name of the window you want to center in the first line, of course.

To see the names of all open windows use:

`wmctrl -l`

Comment: just a question, is there  PIP version? i dont want the user to need to install this